# Optional.ofNullable and method chaining

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I was surprised by `Optional.ofNullable` method. Some day I wrote a function that supposed to return an Optional:

```
private Optional<Integer> extractFirstValueFrom(InsightsResponse insight) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(insight.getValues().get(0).getValue());
}
```

I mistakenly thought that `Optional.ofNullable` will prevent any `NullPointerExceptions` inside of argument expression.

Now I think I know that it was very foolish idea. Java have to resolve arguments first to pass it to `Optional.ofNullable` invocation.

But I have a question. Is there a nice and good way to accomplish my goal? I would like to obtain from expression `insight.getValues().get(0).getValue()` some Integer value or null. Null can be each one of the expressions: `insight.getValues()` or `insight.getValues().get(0)`.

I know that I can just put this in try/catch block but I am wondering if there is more elegant solution.

Comment: In your case `insight` is null. It's much better to never pass null to methods rather than check for null inside methods.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

If you have no idea what can be `null`, or want to check everything for `null`, the only way is to chain calls to [`Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and if the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result. Otherwise return an empty Optional.

As such, if the mapper return `null`, an empty `Optional` will be returned, which allows to chain calls.

```
Optional.ofNullable(insight)
        .map(i -> i.getValues())
        .map(values -> values.get(0))
        .map(v -> v.getValue())
        .orElse(0);
```

The final call to [`orElse(0)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) allows to return the default value 0 if any mapper returned `null`.

Answer (score 4):

smth like this should work

```
Optional.ofNullable(insight.getValues()).map(vals -> vals.get(0)).map(v -> v.getValue())
```

well, according to the sample code given, as `#extractFirstValueFrom` do not contain neither `@Nullable` nor checks for null like Guava's `checkNotNull()`, let's assume that `insight` is always `something`. thus wrapping `Optional.ofNullable(insight.getValues())` into `Option` would not result with `NPE`. then call chain of transformations is composed (each results with `Optional`) that lead to result `Optional<Integer>` that might be either `Some` or `None`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Optional<Integer> extractFirstValueFrom(InsightsResponse insight) {
    AtomicReference<Optional<Integer>> result = new AtomicReference<>(Optional.empty());
    Optional.ofNullable(insight.getValues().get(0)).ifPresent(ele -> result.set(Optional.ofNullable(ele.getValue())));
    return result.get();
}
```

I think sometiems you could use `ifPresent` Api as a null-safe operation.
the `java.util.Optional#map` used `ifPresent` Api similarly.