# Advantages of using a (flat)map over a simple null check?

Tags: java

I was reading the below source, and I was wondering why on earth I'd use the flatmap way. As I see it a lot more objects are instantiated, code executed than in the simple null check via if statement, which will terminate on the first null and not bother to check the others and fits nice and neatly in wrapper.

As I see it the if check is faster + more memory safe(the speed is really crucial for me as I usually only have 2-3 milliseconds for a lot of code to execute, if at all)

**What are the advantages of using the "(flat)Map" optional way? Why should I consider switching to it?**

From http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/

```
class Outer {
    Nested nested;
}

class Nested {
    Inner inner;
}

class Inner {
    String foo;
}
```

> In order to resolve the inner string foo of an outer instance you have to add multiple null checks to prevent possible NullPointerExceptions:

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
if (outer != null && outer.nested != null && outer.nested.inner != null) {
    System.out.println(outer.nested.inner.foo);
}
```

> The same behavior can be obtained by utilizing optionals flatMap operation:

```
Optional.of(new Outer())
    .flatMap(o -> Optional.ofNullable(o.nested))
    .flatMap(n -> Optional.ofNullable(n.inner))
    .flatMap(i -> Optional.ofNullable(i.foo))
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I would use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337020/optional-ofnullable-and-method-chaining, i.e. not `flatMap` but `map`...

Comment: It seems the latter will check on `inner.foo` as well. Other than that, I wouldn't use that idiom - way too convoluted for what it actually does. But I guess it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: I'm more interested in the WHY I should consider switching, as speed is really crucial to me. Not perse the code style. Are there advantages i'm not aware of, etc... I'm really just starting to explore lambda's and stuff, even though I have 15 years of experience doing it the "old fashioned" way.

Comment: IMO it is just an example of how `flatMap` can be chained

Comment: ... highlighted the actual question since everybody seems to be reading over it

Comment: @MichaelDibbets That's just it. For one, `flatMap` is definitely not the right operation. If there is a question, it is between `map` and simply doing the `null` checks. And that is opinion-based.

Comment: I always said that encapsulation was overvalued.

Comment: I guess the responses you got so far could also be read as: "nobody knows about any advantages". Probably this is really just an example using Optional an flatMap. And if performance is an issue ... then why waste time in understanding something that performs less optimal anyway.

Comment: It's highly unlikely to me that creating `Optional` instances and using magical stream operators would be more efficient than a mere boolean check with no overhead.

Comment: @Jägermeister because I like to have a foundation for opinions I hold, and choices I make when using something. And i'm hoping for someone to reply who did some testing or who understands some of the advantages I can't see. My gut feeling is keep using if statements, but i'd like to be affirmed, or be made aware or something different what is a huge bonus.

Comment: The choice I would make would probably depend on the context... but either way, it is opinion-based. Such questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @weston can you eloborate that in an answer? I'm curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `Optional`'s use would be clearer in a wider streaming context, not a one liner.

Suppose we were dealing with an `ArrayList` of `Outers` called `items` and the requirement is to get a stream of the `foo` strings if present.

We could do this:

```
//bad example, read on
Stream<String> allFoos = list.stream()
            .filter(o -> o != null && o.nested != null && o.nested.inner != null)
            .map(o -> o.nested.inner.foo);
```

But I've had to repeat myself, about how to get the string from an outer (`o != null && o.nested != null && o.nested.inner != null` and `o.nested.inner.foo`)

```
Stream<String> allFoos =
        list.stream()
                .map(o -> Optional.ofNullable(o)
                        .map(t -> t.nested)
                        .map(n -> n.inner)
                        .map(i -> i.foo))
                .filter(s -> s.isPresent())
                .map(s -> s.get());
```

This also gives me an easy way to insert default values:

```
Stream<String> allFoos =
            list.stream()
                    .map(o -> Optional.ofNullable(o)
                            .map(t -> t.nested)
                            .map(n -> n.inner)
                            .map(i -> i.foo)
                            .orElse("Missing"));
```

The alternative might look like this:

```
//bad example (IMO)
Stream<String> allFoos = list.stream()
            .map(o -> o != null && o.nested != null && o.nested.inner != null ?
                    o.nested.inner.foo : "Missing");
```

Comment: What do you mean by, i've had tot repeat myself?

Comment: Okay, so what I gather is the use of this structure gives more room to insert default values in case of null instead of getting an ugly mess of nested if statements and elses. Is that correct?

Comment: That's one use case, sure.

Comment: It also gives you typesafety around nulls, e.g. I can't get the flat maps in the wrong order, it won't compile, but I could get the `!= null` tests in the wrong order.

Comment: that is actually quite a good thing to consider, the compilation check :-) god knows I screw that up often enough hehe.

Comment: However a good test suite can make type safety and my points about incorrect null check order redundant anyway http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2016/05/01/TypeWars.html

Comment: @weston You dont need to use `.flatMap(t -> Optional.ofNullable(t.nested)` and so on to chain the optional. You can just use the `map` method like this instead: `.map(t -> t.nested)`. If `t.nested` is null, the `map` method will yield an empty optional.

Comment: @marstran I saw the comments, but I couldn't get `map` that to work like that before, much better now, thanks