# Java. Function with possibly throwable params (NullpointerException)?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

When I have a number of expressions that can throw an exception, for example:

```
instanceObj.final_doc_type = instance.getFinalDocument().getValue().getType().getValue();
instanceObj.final_doc_date = instance.getFinalDocument().getValue().getDate().toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
instanceObj.appeal_date = instance.getFinalDocument().getValue().getAppealDate().getValue().toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
...
instanceObj.start_doc_type = instance.getStartDocument().getValue().getDocType().getValue();
instanceObj.apeealed_type = instance.getStartDocument().getValue().getApeealedType().getValue();
instanceObj.declarers_list_mult_id = instance.getStartDocument().getValue().getDeclarers().getValue().getString();
...
```

is there any method to handle these expressions by some **one** **function** that will return some default value (or null) IF a parameter is invalid and throws an exception - this can take place if, for example:

```
instance.getFinalDocument().getValue().getDate() = null
```

So that I don't need to surround each expression with try-catch block or check every point for null.

Comment: `Optional.fromNullable(instance).map(Instance::getFinalDocument).map(Document::getValue)` etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional.ofNullable and method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337020/optional-ofnullable-and-method-chaining)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

```
instanceObj.final_doc_type = 
    Optional.ofNullable(instance)
      .map(Instance::getFinalDocument)
      .map(Document::getValue)
      .map(Value::getType)
      .map(Type::getValue)
      .orElse(null);
```

This sets `final_doc_type` to `null` if anything in the chain is `null`.

If you only want to set its value in the case of a non-null value, remove the assignment, and change the `orElse` to `ifPresent`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(instance)
    /* ... */
    .ifPresent(t -> instanceObj.final_doc_type = t);
```