# Java - Check Not Null for a number, else assign default string value

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I am looking for a way to set the default value of a variable depending on whether a value is null or not.

The value in question is a double, and the default value (if that value is null) should be a string.

I tried using the following way but it failed because .orElse expects a double (aka same data  type as "value"). 
Is there any Java methods that I can use to achieve that?

```
Double value = 8.0;
Optional.ofNullable(value).orElse("not found")
```

Comment: What about a good old ternary? `(value != null) ? value : "not found"`

Comment: @David that gives type error

Comment: Well if you want a string, just cast it or build it into a string `(value != null) ? ""+value : "not found"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional.ofNullable and method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337020/optional-ofnullable-and-method-chaining)

Comment: It seems like a bizarre concept - the default value of a ```double``` is supposed to be a ```String```.  Why is this useful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not far, just map the value:

```
String strDouble = Optional.ofNullable(value).map(Objects::toString).orElse("not found");
```

Answer (score 1):

Version of your approach which compiles:

```
Object result = Optional.<Object>ofNullable(value).orElse("not found");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the left side of the the assignment operator can be either a `Double` or a `String`, the best that can be done is to specify its type as `Object`.

This will work:

```
Object value2 = Optional.<Object>ofNullable(value).orElse("not found");
```

(i.e. The only shared class in the class hierarchy for `Double` and `String` is `Object)`

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to do when you have null.

If you can use a default long value - then use your approach and instead of the string put the default value in the `orElse`.

If you just want to know if a null was passed, and if so do something different, but you don't want to have `==null`, you can use the `Optional::isPresent` call inside an `if`.

If not having a value is not a state you can tolerate, you can use `Optional::orElseThrow` to throw an Exception.

Finally, if you just want to do something if you indeed have a value, take a look at `Optional::ifPresent` - it is the most fitting for this scenario.

---

If you detail your use-case a bit more, I'll try to fine-tune this answer to fit better.

These are all the APIs for java 8, in later versions you have some more flexibility.